# Dynamic parameter and query

Tags: asp.net, search

I'm creating a search engine for my asp page.There are 15 pieces filtering options like Price,Date,Name etc.
Also,The use of Filtering Options is optional.If the filtering options are left blank,search will be made.
I found a solution by using if and  string.

```
string sorgu = "";
dbcommand cmd = CommandClassım.YeniCommand();
sorgu += "Select * From Urunler Where ";
if(UrunAdi.Text != string.Empty)
{
sorgu += "UrunAdi = @UrunAdi";
dbparameters prm = cmd.createparameter();
prm.Parametername = "@UrunAdi";
prm.Value = UrunAdi.Text;
prm.DbType = DbType.String;
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
}
cmd.CommandText = sorgu;
```

it's running upper code without problem.However,I want to using a parameter to filter dynamic.
So,the user choose those categories through checkbox inside search engine.

When I try to run below code,I got the following error.

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@cat0".
```

Code:

```
string sorgu = "";
DbCommand cmd = CommandClassım.YeniCommand();
sorgu += "Select * From Urunler Where ";
DbParameter prm = cmd.CreateParameter;
for(int i = 0; i < Category.Length; i++)
{
sorgu += "Kategori = @cat" + i.ToString();
prm.ParameterName = "@cat" + i.ToString();
prm.Value = Category.Value;
prm.DbType = DbType.String;
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
}
cmd.CommandText = sorgu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch, but could it be that you're not providing the indexer for Category?

```
prm.Value = Category.Value;
```

I would think it should be:

```
prm.Value = Category[i].Value;
```

Comment: @Tim- First of all,thanks for your interesting.As you mentioned,I couldn't it.So,I got same the error.

Comment: @Selo - At what line does it give you the error?  Also, your command string `sorgu` will most likely not work if you have more than one category selected, as it will look like this:  `Select * From Urnler Where Kategori=@cat0Kategori=@cat1Kategori=@cat3` and so on.

Comment: @Tim- As you said,I'm using a query.But,I got same the error.Also, I'm receiving an error in "cmd.parameters.add(prm);" line.

Comment: @Selo - another hunch, but try declaring the command text (with the paremeters) first.  See if that takes care of both the Must declare scalar variable and the cmd.parameters.add(prm) error. If that doesn't, update your question with the latest code and error messages and where they're happening at, and I'll take another look.